# JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to retrieve the data from the database using the `json` object. But when i call the servlet, the Jquery will returns `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data` This error only shows when the response contains more data.

My script is :

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
        url: "VComment",
        data:'comm='+encodeURIComponent(comm)+'&'+'data-id='+encodeURIComponent(dataid)+'&'+'data-alid='+encodeURIComponent(dataalid),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            if(data.success)
            {
                    var newcommhtml = '<div id="c0'+thecid+'" class="cnew clearfix"> <section class="c-author">';
                    newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<h3>Anonymous</h3>';
                    newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<span class="pubdate">'+month+' '+day+', '+year+'</span> </section>';
                    newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<section class="c-content">';
                    newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<img src="images/green-avatar.png" alt="avatar" width="80" height="80" class="ava">';
                    newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<p>'+nl2br(data.commentInfo.comment)+'</p> </section></div>';

                    var thelm = "#c0"+thecid;
                    commwrap.append(newcommhtml);
                    $(thelm).hide().fadeIn('slow');

                    setTimeout(function() { $(thelm).addClass('green'); }, 800);

                    $("#comm").val("");
                    thecid++;

                    if(errorspan.html() != null) {
                        errorspan.remove();
                    }
            }

          },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
         alert("error"+errorThrown);
         console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
      },
});
```

And the response received..

```
    {"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"rreter","itemId":0}}
    {"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"dfdsfdd","itemId":0}}
    {"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"xzdfdsfdd","itemId":0}}
    {"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"sdfsd fsdfs","itemId":0}}
    {"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"sdsd","itemId":0}}
    {"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"dd","itemId":0}}
    {"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"dddf","itemId":0}}
```

Servlet code :

```
      while(rs.next()){
            Commenter comment = new Commenter();
            comment.setUname(rs.getString("uname").trim());
            comment.setComment(rs.getString("comments").trim());
            commentObj=gson.toJsonTree(comment);
            myObj.add("commentInfo", commentObj);
            out.println(myObj.toString());
            }
```

Please anyone tell me how to solve this problem ... Thanks....

Comment: Well, the response is not valid JSON. `{...} {...}` is not valid. `{...}` and `[{...},{...}]` would be. Fix your server code yo create valid JSON.

Comment: The output is not valid JSON, so jQuery is not able to parse it.

Comment: @Felix Kling But I don't know how to pass it in array from servlet. Please tell me how to pass the values in array...I tried this in different ways but none of them are worked for me....

Comment: Convert an *array* of comments to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code I think It may solve Your problem :

```
        ArrayList<JSONObject> CommArray=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

         while(rs.next()){
            JSONObject Obj = new JSONObject();
            Obj.put("uname",rs.getString("uname").trim());     //Adds your uname to Object
            Obj.put("comment",rs.getString("comments").trim());//Adds your comment to Object
            CommArray.add(Obj);                                //Inserts your Object to ArrayList
            System.out.println(rs.getString("comments").trim());
            }    
         JSONArray arrayObj=JSONArray.fromObject(CommArray);//Converts the Array List to JSONArray
         commentObj=gson.toJsonTree(arrayObj);   //Converts the JSONArray to Jsontree
         myObj.add("commentInfo", commentObj);   //Adds the Tree to JsonObject as commentInfo Array
         out.println(myObj.toString());        //Prints the result
         rs.close();                                                              
         stmt.close();                                                            
         stmt = null;                                                             
         conn.close();                                                            
         conn = null;                                                  

     }                                                              
     catch(Exception e){}
```

I hope this solves Your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have several indenpendant JSON objects in the response. Wrap them in an array and you will be better off

```
[{"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"rreter","itemId":0}},
{"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"dfdsfdd","itemId":0}},
{"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"xzdfdsfdd","itemId":0}},
{"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"sdfsd fsdfs","itemId":0}},
{"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"sdsd","itemId":0}},
{"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"dd","itemId":0}},
{"success":true,"commentInfo":{"uname":"shyam","comment":"dddf","itemId":0}}]
```

and the change the function to:

```
success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
       for(var i = 0,len=data.length;i<len;i += 1){
        if(data[i].success)
        {
          //code
        }
       }
    }
```

on the server side just change to

```
out.println("[");
Boolean first = true
while(rs.next()){
        Commenter comment = new Commenter();
        comment.setUname(rs.getString("uname").trim());
        comment.setComment(rs.getString("comments").trim());
        commentObj=gson.toJsonTree(comment);
        myObj.add("commentInfo", commentObj);
        if(!first){
          out.print(",");
        } else {
          first = false;
        }
        out.println(myObj.toString());
        }   
out.println("]");
```

Comment: *"the trailing comma will be ignored by the JSON parser"* I don't think so. http://jsfiddle.net/pYELD/

Comment: @FelixKling well my did actually parseit :) but tryingadifferentI getthe sameresultas you

Answer (score 0):

Try to temporally change the `dataType` and make the same bad request, output the response e let's see what's wrong.